# Why does MySQL do a scan for update but lookup for select

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-performance

I have these 2 queries. As you can see its doing a lookup in TabRedemption for orderItemID. The select takes a fraction of a second while the update takes ~30 seconds.

Why does MySQL resort to a full index scan in the update, and how can I stop this. It already has a foreign key constraint and and index.

```
select RedemptionID from TabRedemption where orderItemID in
   (SELECT OrderItemID FROM TabOrderDetails WHERE OrderId = 4559775);
```

[image]

```
UPDATE TabRedemption SET active = 1 where orderItemID in
   (SELECT OrderItemID FROM TabOrderDetails WHERE OrderId = 4559775);
```

[image]

Strangely if I resolve the subquery manually its fast.

```
UPDATE TabRedemption SET active = 1 where orderItemID in (2579027);
```

I've noticed that if I use a `update with join` query its fast, but I dont want to do that because its not supported in h2database.

On a side note MS SQLServer does this fine.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the EXPLAIN and table definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best *workaround*:

```
UPDATE  TabRedemption
    JOIN  TabOrderDetails USING(orderItemID)
    SET TabRedemption.active = 1
    WHERE  TabOrderDetails.OrderId = 4559775;
```

(or something close to that)

The *answer* is that `SELECT` and `UPDATE` use different parsers.  The workaround is to add a second table to the UPDATE because it will then use the SELECT parser.

The difference in parsers is being addressed by Oracle in MySQL 5.7.

Keep in mind that the pattern "IN ( SELECT ... )" optimizes poorly in many cases (although apparently not your case).